# Google Play Leaderboards Hack

Tags: root-access, google-play-games

As you may have noticed, on plenty of Android games with top scores, they are linked to the Google Play Games Leaderboards. Of course these will contain plenty of hacked scores. I was wondering **How do you hack a game score and have it appear on the online leaderboards?**

I have tried editing local files containing scores etc. and I've tried using game guardian and both worked for changing my offline score.

Games like Flappy Bird, Crossy Road and Don't Tap The White Tile are the sorts of games which I have successfully modded offline and wish to mod online.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I could only understand... if you have a thousand dollar "high-score" bet on the table to have to spend time trying to hack leaderboards. Anyway...

Your best bet IMO would be to write an Xposed module, that loops into a static method in the Google Play Games API library bundled in each game to (re)set the `private String` or `private Integer` that holds the score.

You'll have to use Xposed (IMO) so the Google Play library doesn't detect the modified code via md5 check.

If you have questions about programming this, go ask on Stack Overflow, lots of people ready to help there.

Hope this provides some insight.